# Export any kind of object for a further reuse?

Tags: .net-3.5

I'm working on different data structures which are obtained after long computation time.

Is there a way to create an object in a first build and use this same object in a second build (for the sake of time computation) ??

I need to do this without specifying the type of object..

Thanks

Comment: Your question (if there is one), is too vague to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose the thing you need is called **serialization**. Maybe these will help you:

[Object Serialization using C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/objserial.aspx)

[XmlSerializer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx)